# Google NID Cookie

Tags: cookies

I'm not sure if this is the right stack to ask this in so if not please let me know!

I am trying to get a handle on what cookies are used on a site and what they are for. When I initially did a cookie scan I noticed a cookie names NID which was set by google.

I have tried to research this cookie and can see it is used by Google for advertising purposes.

But I am confused about why and where this is being set, the site I am looking at does not use advertising anywhere, although it does use embedded YouTube videos.

Can anyone shed any light on when and why this cookie is set?

Answer (score 4):

[according to Google](https://policies.google.com/technologies/types?hl=en)

> Most Google users will have a preferences cookie called ‘NID’ in their browsers. A browser sends this cookie with requests to Google’s sites. The NID cookie contains a unique ID Google uses to remember your preferences and other information, such as your preferred language (e.g. English), how many search results you wish to have shown per page (e.g. 10 or 20), and whether or not you wish to have Google’s SafeSearch filter turned on.

Comment: If this is accurate, I just noticed something quite surprising. As expected, with Chrome in incognito mode, this cookie does not get applied - but with Edge in private mode, it does get applied. That means Google can track you for the duration of a session in private mode in Edge - but not in incognito mode in Chrome. I find this quite surprising. Why would Microsoft enable tracking for Google that Google itself doesn't even do?

Comment: @mindplay.dk Thought I was seeing the same thing. Further testing reveals both browsers behave similarly (perhaps this has changed in the past 6 months though?) - the NID cookie is only set once you agree to Google's cookie policy when visiting Google search (or possibly other Google sites?), and this must be done within the incognito session. Once that is set, it will appear in the cookies list for other sites also, until you terminate your incognito session.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the cookie was hammered incessantly by the url https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.org  Which was being used by CookieBro & FeedBro RSS feeder browser addons for retrieving icons associated with various domains. The cookie can be dropped by either an addon or by google itself.

I used **cookie log** via cookiebro addon for [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookiebro/) & [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiebro/lpmockibcakojclnfmhchibmdpmollgn) to detect these cookies in realtime, its one of a kind. However I did not realize it was cookiebro dropping them until the next step below.

To see what background connection is occuring when these cookies are placed,  enter the following firefox url: about:cache?storage=disk&context= and you will see when and where the google url being connected to.

It is said this cookie is for [targeting & ADS](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/NID) and the google's settings are integrated to make the cookie inconvenient to delete for Google users.